# Configuring splash screen to fully cover the boot

Tags: boot, xubuntu, xfce, plymouth

I'm trying to set the splash screens for the whole boot, from the selection in grub until DE fully loads. My DE is xfce 4.10, running xubuntu 13.10.

Now, I have the default plymounth xubuntu theme, which works good, except that it takes ~3-5sec to show since grub starts to load ubuntu (there is a blank screen for that period), after the plymounth splash, there is a ~2-3sec blank screen again, then (I have autologin) the xfce splash screen appears but only for ~1-2sec and the the xfce continue to boot. During that xfce boot the desktop has no wallpaper, nor the theme is applied so it looks ugly.

It would be nice to have the xfce splash appered right after the plymounth splash and have it visible for the whole DE boot (or at least until the wallpaper and theme load)
If I remember correctly, KDE works like this, it has its splash screen which is shown until KDE boots.

Also, there should be a splash screen when shutting down the system but that screen only appears for ~1sec and then it switch to text mode until the system is shutted down.

Any idea of how to solve this?